# requestAnimationFrame: Explanation of returning a Framerate

Tags: javascript, jquery, frame-rate, requestanimationframe

So I found this helpful piece of code and used it to provide an instantaneous framerate of some animation I have created. I was hoping someone could help me understand how it functions?

Here is my code:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>

window.countFPS = (function () {
  var lastLoop = (new Date()).getMilliseconds();
  var count = 1;
  var fps = 0;

  return function () {
    var currentLoop = (new Date()).getMilliseconds();
    if (lastLoop > currentLoop) {
      fps = count;
      count = 1;
    } else {
      count += 1;
    }
    lastLoop = currentLoop;
    return fps;
  };
}());

(function loop() {
  requestAnimationFrame(function () {
    $('#out').html(countFPS());
    loop();
  });
}());
```

The `#out` leads to an output tag, if it was not obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the whole magic happens in the requestAnimationFrame, which is an "black box" that really does everything necessary for the function to work. it tells you that "now i have free resources to do a new picture render"

the whole thing just wraps this up and measures the time differences between these moments of "i can render a new frame now" moments. an example: first it was 24th of october, 2015, 10:55:10.1492**169**, then it was 24th of october, 2015, 10:55:10.1492**525**. therefore the frequency of being able to draw a new frame is 356 miliseconds. if the cpu were overloaded more, it would be higher

as pointy mentions, it does eat some resources up (but a very negligible pitiful amount of resources) while showing some useful statistics about how often does it have resources to render a new frame - providing a very useful tool to measure effectiveness of currently running scripts

Comment: Ah! thanks it's much clearer to me now! That was a nice explanation thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The "countFPS" function just compares the milliseconds of the timestamp recorded on its prior invocation with that on its current invocation. If the new millisecond counter is larger than the previous one, it assumes it's in the same second and so another "frame" is counted (the `count` variable is incremented). If not, then it resets the counter to 1.

Why it starts the counter off at 2, or indeed why this code exists at all, is not clear. I don't see how this is particularly "helpful" code. The `requestAnimationFrame()` function is intended to match the low-level refresh rate on the display, which on any modern LCD screen will be 60Hz. Even if it's different, your code really can't do anything about it. Running this code while you're doing animation adds the overhead of performing that DOM update (changing the contents of the "out" element), which directly impacts the amount of work your own animation can do.

Comment: The counter starting at 2 was a mistype apologies.

Comment: As to why it exists it is simply to monitor the FPS of the current animation running. I tested its results with googles FPS counter and it seemed to be pretty accurate. Thanks for the explanation though. It's greatly appreciated.

Comment: Actually I'm still confused on how it works. Obviously its measuring the correct FPS (results align with google FPS counter). I'm not sure if I understood your explanation.